# I can't see the photo I added to my portfolio site

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to create my own portfolio site using HTML and CSS. First, I want to show what I did in the index.

```css
header {
  height: 46rem;
}

header.image {
  background-image: url('https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w300/2023/09/instagram-image-size.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 46rem;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Kerimcan Uğurlu @kerimcan.ugurlu</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

As you can see from what I wrote, I think I did everything correctly, but the photos I added do not appear as the background. In fact, the photo I added does not appear at all.

Comment: Did you inspect the element with your browser? When you don't see your styles on it, it tells you your selector is wrong (assuming other styles are working). That's a tool you should have in your kit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) The selector needs to be `header .image { ... }` with a space in between to indicate that `.image` is a *descendent*  element of `header`. (Without that space it would only select a `header` element which has an `.image` class itself)

2.) `opacity: 0` will make the element fully transparent = invisible, so change that to another value...

```css
header {
  height: 46rem;
}

header .image {
  background-image: url('https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w300/2023/09/instagram-image-size.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 46rem;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Kerimcan Uğurlu @kerimcan.ugurlu</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

But I suppose you want to have that image as a background for the whole `header` element, so you shouldn't use a separate `div` for it, but instead define it as `background-image` for `header` itself (or maybe for `header h1`?):

```css
header {
  height: 46rem;
  background-image: url('https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w300/2023/09/instagram-image-size.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Kerimcan Uğurlu @kerimcan.ugurlu</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```